# Can the server get a long-lived access token with the code in `signedRequest`?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Is the `code` property of `authResponse.signedRequest` (in the Facebook JavaScript API) useful? I'm generating one like this:

```js
FB.login({ scope: "email" }, function(r) {
    console.log([
        function(d){ return d.split('.')[1]; },
        function(d){ return atob(d.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/')); },
        JSON.parse,
        function(d){ return d.code; }
    ].reduce(
        function(acc, f) { return f(acc); },
        r.authResponse.signedRequest
    ));
});
```

[The docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) say this:

> `code`: an OAuth Code which can be exchanged for a valid user access token via a [subsequent server-side request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

…but that link redirects to Facebook Login home page. I found the `/oauth/access_token` endpoint documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/), but it requires a `redirect_uri` parameter, and there isn't one in this case.

Comment: When using FB.login, you get a short-lived user access token already – and that’s what you need to switch for a long-lived one.

Comment: @CBroe That's fair, I was just interested in whether `code` is useful too since it's present and documented. Maybe it's just in there for the SDK's benefit and it's exposed so that you can verify the payload's signature.

Comment: @CBroe FWIW, if you're pretty sure that this is correct (and the docs are wrong about that property), you're welcome to submit it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: What I’m sure about is that the code can only be used to be exchanged for a token once (they made that change a few month ago to comply with the OAuth 2.0 spec) – but I’m not sure if this code is associated with the token you also get in the signed_request, or if it still “fresh” and unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [CBroe suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521628/can-the-server-get-a-long-lived-access-token-with-the-code-in-signedrequest#comment27237580_18521628), the `code` in this response appears to have already been used by the JavaScript SDK to create a short-lived token.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit of a necro-bump, but for anyone else who stumbles upon this...

You can POST the code to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
```

In the form body, you want:

```
client_id: your_app_client_id
client_secret: you_app_client_secret
grant_type: "authorization_code"
redirect_uri: ""
code: code_from_signed_request
```

The blank redirect_uri is the key. You *must* supply a blank string ... omitting the field doesn't work.

Since you need to supply your client secret, you don't want to do this client-side. Send the code to some method on your server to do it, and return the access code to your client.